# Добавление новых разделов в Android-приложение

Tags: android

У меня приложение справочник. Планируется постоянно добавлять новые разделы.
Как это делается?

Comment: Вопрос в смысле обновления приложения, добавил новый код а дальше?

Comment: а не проще грузить новые разделы с сервера? тогда вам вообще не надо будет приложение обновлять для этого

Comment: Вам необходимо пояснить вопрос, а точней опишите откуда вы будете брать данные, что у вас сделано и какой результат вам нужен

Comment: в приложение будут добавляться новые строковые ресурсы, изображения, ну и код со ссылками на них

Comment: Вы объясните, что в итгедолжно получиться.. Вам нужна реализация интерфейса? Или же вы хотите реализацию быкэнда. Если да, то объясните, какой конкретно вопрос Вас интересует, никто же не будет писать за Вас Ваше приложение.

Comment: Плюсом, все пояснения в комментариях желательно вынести в вопрос